# To post on facebook page using javascript SDK with page access token

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to post to my facebook's wall using javascript SDK. I am first getting user access token. Then using user access token i am getting page access token and including it while posting to a wall. I'm getting following error [image]

here's my code : First am trying to login using FB.login

```
FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.'+JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    },{scope: 'manage_pages,publish_pages'});
```

Then trying to post to a page.

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { 
               console.log('login status',response);
            if(!(response.status === 'connected')){
                location.href = './fb-login.html';
                } else {
                    uID = response.authResponse.userID;
                    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    console.log('accesstoken::',response.authResponse.accessToken);
                    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, {  access_token : accessToken } ,function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                    //get list of pages
                    if(accessToken!=null){
                        FB.api('/me/accounts','get',{  access_token : accessToken },function(response){
                            console.log('resp of pages',response);
                            if(response!=null){
                                var data = response.data;
                                pageAccessToken= data[0].access_token;
                                console.log('pageAccessToken::',pageAccessToken);

                                FB.api('/6599048*******/feed', 'post', {message :body, access_token : pageAccessToken }, function(response) {
                                    console.log('response',response)
                                    if (!response || response.error) {
                                        alert('Error occured');
                                    } else {
                                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                                    }
                                });
                                }

                        });
                    }
```

Comment: _Can_ you even post to user profiles _as_ a page? Not sure about that. In any case, you would have to replace `me` with the actual user id - otherwise, it automatically refers _to_ the page, when the request is made using a page access token.

Comment: Hi @misorude I've given page Id and tried. Still getting same error

Comment: Then you probably don’t have all the necessary permissions to begin with. In your code you are asking for permissions in the wrong place  - you need to call `FB.login` with a parameter containing the `scope` property; trying to supply that parameter when making API calls using `FB.api` makes no sense to begin with, that is not how it works.

Comment: so where do you want to post? on a page or on a user wall? and why add the user_likes and publish_to_groups permissions? what for?

Comment: @misorude the code I've pasted here is after the FB.login. I used FB.login and got my username in response. After that on click of a button the above one executes.

Comment: @luschn I updated the code removing those unnecessary permissions and I wanted to post on a page.

Comment: _“I updated the code removing those unnecessary permissions”_ - they are _all_ unnecessary at those points. Again: Passing a `scope` to FB.api makes _zero_ sense.

Comment: Check your access tokens, both user and page, using the access token debug tool, and see what that reports.

Comment: @misorude. I've checked both of them in the Graph API explorer and even hardcoded in the code too and checked. still same error.

Comment: So it shows all the permissions you were asking for as granted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197200/discussion-between-77-and-misorude).

Comment: I've updated the code. Now i am receiving "Invalid parameter". "Missing message or attachment"

Comment: `{message: body, access_token: pageAccessToken }` - see the difference to your code

Comment: Hi @luschn, Replaced the params. Thanks a lot. It got posted.

Comment: Thanks both of you!

Comment: you should delete this question, since you even updated your question to include the correct code there is no point in creating an answer. keep it clean.